# Qobject::connect: invalid null parameter when running Kate application in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kate

I am using Linux Mint Sarah and I am receiving this error whenever I use the command "kate file_name". I already updated my Kate and I believe it is already at its latest version.

```
QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::returnPressed() to KUrlRequester::returnPressed()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::returnPressed(QString) to KUrlRequester::returnPressed(QString)
Setting the name of  0x10e71d0  to  "org.kde.ActivityManager.ActivityTemplates"
Setting the name of  0x11130a0  to  "org.kde.ActivityManager.RunApplication"
Setting the name of  0x11019c0  to  "org.kde.ActivityManager.Resources.Scoring"
Creating directory:  "/root/.local/share/kactivitymanagerd/resources/"
KActivities: Database connection:  "kactivities_db_resources_139836748884160_readwrite" 
    query_only:          QVariant(qlonglong, 0) 
    journal_mode:        QVariant(QString, "wal") 
    wal_autocheckpoint:  QVariant(qlonglong, 100) 
    synchronous:         QVariant(qlonglong, 1)
Service started, version: 7.0.0
```

Comment: while i have used kate for ages it stopped working well without some effort in Mint 17.3 and really never got 100% right in Mint 18.  I switched to Geany.

As said below, those errors are from trying to do kde-integration-specific stuff which isn't present in MATE or Cinnamon.

Answer (score 0):

What you get here is a kde's developers mistake and they should fix it. These warnings should not affect you however, just ignore it.

You can try to fill a bug report at [KDE Bugs page](https://bugs.kde.org/) to let them now.

Comment: the problem is I can't use again the console since the app did not exit properly in the command, I have to open another console. what can i do to resolve this?

Comment: @Gibs: I do not understand, what do you mean by 'app did not exit properly'? And what by 'I can't use again the console'?

Comment: what i mean is for example, you open a console window, then type "kate file_name". Although the filename is opened properly in kate, the console however does not return to the command line, rather, it stays to the error wherein I can not type anything from the console, making the console useless for other task. If i want to type other commands i have to open another console.

Comment: @Gibs: this is a normal behaviour. Even without errors, you wouldn't be able to do anything in this console until kate exits.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Kate from the Konsole, start it by typing

```
kate &
```

That will start Kate in the background, and give you back the Konsole. If you ever need to run Kate in the foreground, as is happening now just type "fg " at the command prompt.  Leave out my quotation marks, of course.  This is a standard Linux function.